# Вывести весь список из базы данных Flask используя sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Нам надо вывести весь список из базы данных в таблицу.

Попробовали использовать `query.all()` — не получилось.А нужно вывести из базы данных значения Session_cinema
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что посоветуете?

Comment: список чего? уточните, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit].

Comment: Каким способом пытались вывести? Приложите пример кода, который выводит данные.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте код в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения. Для этого используйте ссылку «[edit]», расположенную под метками вопроса.